# Finishing California redwood for a bed frame?

Tags: finishing, finish-selection

I'm looking at what finish would be best for a redwood bed frame. I would like the wood to look natural, warmish color, and a bit of a satiny feel. I've done a few trials and here is where I stand (see pics):

- polycrylic satin looks OK but dulls the details in the wood a bit (compared to others I tried) and I seem to be leaving streak marks
- shellac looked better than poly but gets stained by water (experience on a diff project)
- wax looked the best IMO, and felt the best but provide no protection (and redwood is quite soft)
- Danish oil has a nice overall color but made some parts look grayish and other parts look blotchy (could be I haven't applied it correctly).

Would you guys have any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Re. this, *"other parts look blotchy (could be i haven't applied it correctly)"* redwood, like most softwoods, is a blotch-prone wood. Straight oil or the oil in a penetrating finish can be enough to bring this to light.

Comment: FYI this is likely to closed as Answers are going to be primarily opinion-based, and mine is that I'd use nothing you've tested here. I'd go with an oil-based varnish, thinned down to wiping consistency and with maybe three coats applied. Cheap, couldn't be easier to apply and provides a high level of protection on all fronts.

Comment: I've curious what "Howard Wax" is. When I saw that, I thought OPs user name would be "Howard"...

Comment: I'll say this then duck but ..  I would give Tung oil a shot. It'll look amazing and harden nicely too.

Comment: @Graphus you'd have thought so, but, 2.5 years later it's still open. I've started the close campaign, since OP seems to have abandoned it without ever selecting an answer.

Comment: @FreeMan, indeed! Close votes eventually timeout it seems, since I definitely would have voted to close this at the time.

Comment: Wax looked and smelled great but the platform contour of the bed was getting a lot of traffic and it scuffed really easily; I couldn't get oil to look non blotchy, even on the heartwood only pieces. I ended up doing the headboard with minwax poly, and while not super durable, it looks very natural and provides some protection. Thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the wax! I think it looks best, and it provides enough protection. Redwood used to be commonly used for outdoor building projects that would be exposed to water because it is durable - at least the heartwood is.

Because this will be indoor, wax will be fine. You may want to re-apply in a couple of years, but in reality, this wood will endure with strength.

Answer (score 1):

Howards is (I presume we're talking about the same Howard's) "Howards FEED-N-WAX" (google it), it is an "original blend of beeswax, Brazilian carnauba wax, mineral oil, and orange oil".  It smells great and it easy to use (like any of the oils).

I have used it and I like it but I'd worry that it would wear off (the wax would) and leave no protection.  That might not be an issues for a bed (table, countertop, sink surround certainly an issue).

Remember mineral oil does not "dry" or evaporate it just sits there so repeated washings will remove it - again not a problem for a bed.

I used Howards on old redwood walls that had become scuffed and dingy over the years.  A light sand and the Howards did a beautiful job revitalizing that wood.